# How can I show that `Monad` is actually `Applicative` and `Functor`?

Tags: haskell, monads

In Haskell, class `Monad` is declared as:

```
class   Applicative m   =>  Monad   m   where
return  ::  a   ->  m   a
(>>=)   ::  m   a   ->  (a  ->  m   b)  ->  m   b
return  =   pure
```

How can I  show that `Monad` is actually `Applicative`, which is declared like this?

```
class   Functor f   =>  Applicative f   where
pure    ::  a   ->  f   a
(<*>)   ::  f   (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
```

Specifically, how can I write `pure` and `<*>` in terms of `return` and `>>=`?

How can I show that `Monad` is actually `Functor`, which is declared like this?

```
class   Functor f   where
fmap    ::  (a  ->  b)  ->  f   a   ->  f   b
```

Specifically, how can I write `fmap` in terms of `return` and `>>=`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are all in the documentation.

> Specifically, how can I write `pure` and `<*>` in terms of return and `>>=`?

See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad, specifically this section:

> Furthermore, the Monad and Applicative operations should relate as follows:
>
> ```
> pure = return
> (<*>) = ap
> ```

and note that `ap` was a standard Monad function long before Applicative was introduced as a standard part of the language, and is [defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#ap) as `ap m1 m2          = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (x1 x2) }`

`Specifically, how can I write fmap in terms of return and >>=?`

The [Control.Applicative documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html) says:

> As a consequence of these laws, the `Functor` instance for `f` will satisfy
>
> ```
> fmap f x = pure f <*> x
> ```

Which of course, using what I quoted above, you can use to implement `fmap` in terms of `return` and `>>=`.

And as @duplode points out, there are also [liftM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM) for Monads, and [liftA](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA) for Applicatives, which are (essentially, although they're not defined literally that way) synonyms of `fmap`, specialised to their particular type classes.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you might want to mention `liftM` and `liftA`.

Comment: What's interesting about those two is that they are not literally synonyms. They are to `fmap` what `ap` is to `(<*>)`: `liftM f m1 = do { x1 <- m1; return (f x1) }`, and `liftA f a = pure f <*> a`.

Comment: Thanks. how can I write   <*> in terms of return and >>=? how can I write fmap in terms of return and >>=?

Comment: @duplode May I ask what you think of my questions in the above comment?

Comment: @Tim the explanations are all in the answer. Admittedly I gave you the definition of `ap` (which is the same as `<*>`) in terms of `do` notation, but this is just syntactic sugar, so it's easy enough to translate back. I didn't realise you needed it explicitly spelled out, but it would result in `a <*> b = a >>= \f -> b >>= \x -> return (f x)`. And then for `fmap` start from `fmap f x = pure f <*> x` and substitute in `return` for `pure` and the above definition for `<*>`.

Comment: How are do notation and return/>>=   translated to each other?

Comment: @Tim - did you try google? There are [loads](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#Do_notation) of [good](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation) explanations of [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#do-notation) online (including the definitive, and admirably brief, one in the [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14))

Comment: @Tim In addition to what Robin notes, `fmap` in terms of `return` and `(>>=)` is `liftM`, as in my comment above, or, equivalently, `liftM f m = m >>= \x -> return (f x)`